# Why can't I append Nil to a list?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have the following recursive method:

```
def myMethod(foo: List[FooBar], acc: List[MyClass]): List[MyClass] {

   // ... some code ...

   myMethod(foo.tail, acc :+ getMyObject(foo.head).getOrElse(Nil))

}
```

The method `getMyObject` returns optionally an instance of `MyClass`. Unfortunately, I can't compile this because I get this error:

```
[error]  found   : List[Product with Serializable]
[error]  required: List[MyClass]
```

This compile error indicates that I cannot append `Nil` to the list `acc`, so I have to use the following code:

```
def myMethod(foo: List[FooBar], acc: List[MyClass]): List[MyClass] {

   // ... some code ...
   val bar = getMyObject(foo.head)
   myMethod(foo.tail, if (bar.isDefined) acc :+ bar.get else acc)

}
```

However, I would prefer the first approach since it is more concise. Why can't I append `Nil` to a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:+` takes an `n`-elemnt list and an element `x` and returns an `n+1`-element list where the last element is `x`. This means two things:

- There's no argument that you can use as the right operand of `:+` to get a list of the same size
- The right operand of `:+` needs to be of the element type of the list.

So you can do `acc :+ Nil` only if `acc` is a list of lists and even then it won't do what you want since it will put an additional empty list into your list, rather than keeping the list unchanged.

---

The most concise way to solve your problem is `acc ++ bar`. This uses concatenation rather than appending and works because options are seen as collections of 0 or 1 elements. So `acc ++ bar` appends the zero or one elements of `bar` to those of `acc`.

PS: You generally should use pattern matching or higher-order functions to operate on lists, not `head` and `tail`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the append operation :+ takes a non-list value and appends it to the list.  The trouble is Nil and Myclass are different types, so the resulting list takes the most specific type that satisfies both MyClass and Nil.  They are totally unrelated types so you end up getting `Product with Serializable` as the common super type.

To append an element or nothing to a list, wrap that element into a list first. Then concatenate your singleton List or Nil with the old list.

```
myMethod(foo.tail, acc ++ getMyObject(foo.head).map(x => List(x)).getOrElse(Nil))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong operator, use ++ instead

```
myMethod(foo.tail, acc ++ getMyObject(foo.head).map(List(_)).getOrElse(Nil))
```

or

```
myMethod(foo.tail,  getMyObject(foo.head).map(acc :+ _).getOrElse(acc))
```

Comment: `getMyObject` returns an `Option[MyClass]` - so this won't compile